# Number of ways to pick the elements of an array?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, dynamic-programming

How to formulate this problem in code?

**Problem Statement:**

***UPDATED:***

> Find the number of ways to pick the element from the array which are
>   not visited.

We starting from 1,2,.....,n with some (1<= x <= n) number of elements already picked/visited randomly which is given in the input.

Now, we need to find the number of ways we can pick rest of the (n - x) number of elements present in the array, and the way we pick an element is defined as:

On every turn, we can only pick the element which is adjacent(either left or right) to some visited element i.e 
in an *array of elements:*

> **1,2,3,4,5,6** let's say we have visited **3 & 6** then we can now pick
>   **2 or 4 or 5**, as they are unvisited and adjacent to visited nodes, now say we pick 2, so now we can pick **1 or 4 or 5** and continues.

example:

```
input: N = 6(number of elements: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
M = 2(number of visited elements) 
visited elements are = 1, 5

Output: 16(number of ways we can pick the unvisited elements)

ways: 4, 6, 2, 3 
      4, 6, 3, 2
      4, 2, 3, 6
      4, 2, 6, 3
      4, 3, 2, 6
      4, 3, 6, 2
      6, 4, 2, 3
      6, 4, 2, 3
      6, 2, 3, 4
      6, 2, 4, 3 
      2, 6, 4, 3
      2, 6, 3, 4
      2, 4, 6, 3
      2, 4, 3, 6
      2, 3, 4, 6 
      2, 3, 6, 4.
```

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** findings.

Comment: Also, I find the formulation of the problem quite hard to understand. Please consider rewording it, add more explanation and / or more examples.

Comment: @MrSmith42, yes I tried to solve this using recursion. But this was giving TLE, then I realized that we would encounter repeated subproblems in the recursive solution, but was unable to define the state of DP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some analysis of the problem:

- The actual values in the input array are assumed to be 1...n, but these values do not really play a role. These values just represent indexes that are referenced by the other input array, which lists the visited indexes (1-based)
- The list of visited indexes actually cuts the main array into subarrays with smaller sizes. So for example, when `n=6` and `visited=[1,5]`, then the original array [1,2,3,4,5,6] is cut into [2,3,4] and [6]. So it cuts it into sizes 3 and 1. At this point the index numbering loses its purpose, so the problem really is fully described with those two sizes: 3 and 1. To illustrate, the solution for `(n=6, visited=[1,5])` is necessarily the same as for `(n=7, visited[1,2,6])`: the sizes into which the original array is cut, are the same in both cases (in a different order, but that doesn't influence the result).

Algorithm, based on a list of sizes of subarrays (see above):

- The number of ways that *one* such subarray can be visited, is not that difficult: if the subarray's size is 1, there is just one way. If it is greater, then at each pick, there are two possibilities: either you pick from the left side or from the right side. So you get like 2*2*..*2*1 possibilities to pick. This is 2<sup>size-1</sup> possibilities.
- The two outer subarrays are an exception to this, as you can only pick items from the inside-out, so for those the number of ways to visit such a subarray is just 1.
- The number of ways that you can pick items from two subarrays can be determined as follows: count the number of ways to pick from just one of those subarrays, and the number of ways to pick from the other one. Then consider that you can alternate when to pick from one sub array or from the other. This comes down to interweaving the two sub arrays. Let's say the larger of the two sub arrays has *j* elements, and the smaller *k*, then consider there are *j+1* positions where an element from the smaller sub array can be injected (merged) into the larger array. There are ["k multichoose j+1"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) ways ways to inject all elements from the smaller sub array.
- When you have counted the number of ways to merge two subarrays, you actually have an array with a size that is the sum of those two sizes. The above logic can then be applied with this array and the next subarray in the problem specification. The number of ways just multiplies as you merge more subarrays into this growing array. Of course, you don't really deal with the arrays, just with sizes.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript, which applies the above algorithm:

```js
function getSubArraySizes(n, visited) {
    // Translate the problem into a set of sizes (of subarrays)
    let j = 0;
    let sizes = [];
    for (let i of visited) {
        let size = i - j - 1;
        if (size > 0) sizes.push(size);
        j = i;
    }
    let size = n - j;
    if (size > 0) sizes.push(size);
    return sizes;
}

function Combi(n, k) {
    // Count combinations: "from n, take k"
    // See Wikipedia on "Combination"
    let c = 1;
    let end = Math.min(k, n - k);
    for (let i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        c = c * (n-i) / (end-i); // This is floating point
    }
    return c; // ... but result is integer
}

function getPickCount(sizes) {
    // Main function, based on a list of sizes of subarrays
    let count = 0;
    let result = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
        let size = sizes[i];
        // Number of ways to take items from this chunk: 
        // - when items can only be taken from one side: 1
        // - otherwise: every time we have a choice between 2, except for the last remaining item
        let pickCount = i == 0 || i == sizes.length-1 ? 1 : 2 ** (size-1);
        // Number of ways to merge/weave two arrays, where relative order of elements is not changed
        // = a "k multichoice from n". See 
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition
        let weaveCount = count == 0 ? 1 // First time only
            : Combi(size+count, Math.min(count, size));
        // Number of possibilities:
        result *= pickCount * weaveCount;
        // Update the size to be the size of the merged/woven array
        count += size;
    }
    return result;
}

// Demo with the example input (n = 6, visited = 1 and 5)
let result = getPickCount(getSubArraySizes(6, [1, 5]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Okay, I have got few doubts.

Comment: Doubt_1 @trincot:

let pickCount = 2 ** (size-1); 

Subarray which is not bounded by visited elements from both side has got only 1 way to pick its elements,

for example in arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6] && visited = [4, 6]
 , subarray [1, 2, 3] can be visited in only 1 way like 3->2 -> 1.

But the above equation will give: 2 ^(3 - 1) = 4 ways.

Comment: Doubt_2 @trincot: 

Interweaving two subarrays using the formula: C(j + 1, K) is not considering all cases.

For example : [2, 5] & [7, 9, 11] 
here C(4, 2) considering 6 ways as given:

7 9 2 11 5 
7 2 9 5 11
2 7 5 9 11 
2 7 9 5 11 
2 7 9 11 5 
7 2 9 11 5

Other ways possible :

7 9 11 2 5
2 5 7 9 11

Comment: After looking at this question again (after two months), I agree on both comments you made. I have now updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay, for n = 5 arr[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] && visited = [2, 5]

so your getSubArraySizes() function will return [1, 2] but this 
line 

"let pickCount = i == 0 || i == sizes.length-1 ? 1 : 2 ** (size-1);" 

will give 1 pickcount for both sizes though it should return 1 for 0th element and 2 ^ (2-1) = 2 for 1th element.

Comment: How did you come up with this formula for interweaving two subarrays, Combi(size+count, Math.min(count, size)); 


Wiki-Article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition is hard to understand, can you please explain this.

Comment: And according to your previous solution for the number of ways to interweave two arrays, I came up with this formula: Let's just say we have, arr1 = [8,9, 2,1] && arr1 = [3,4,5,6,7] now the bigger array has 5 elements OR 6 positions where we can insert arr1 elements

Comment: So we have C(6, 4) ways. Now if we consider every 2 adjacent elements of arr1 as 1 element we have 3 * C(6, 3) ways. 

Similarly, if we consider every 3 adjacent elements of arr1 as 1 element we have 2*C(6, 2) ways && 

if we consider every 4 adjacent elements of arr1 as 1 element we have 1*C(6, 1) ways 

so total ways to interweave arr1 and arr2 would be: 
C(6, 4) + 3*C(6, 3) + 2*C(6, 2) + 1*C(6, 1)

Do you think this would work?

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is what "n *multichoose* k" achieves. The **C** function gives "n choose k", so without repetition. There is a way to write a formula for where repetition is allowed (so several values of the shorter array end up in the same "gap" somewhere in the larger array), and it can be done with **C**. Just the arguments need to be adjusted. The equation is "n multichoose k" == C(n + k - 1, k). Translate that because in our case *n* is the number of gaps in the larger array, i.e. len(array1) + 1.

Comment: The formula that I derived above and  "n multichoose k" == C(n + k - 1, k), would they give the same result?

Comment: I doubt it as there are cases where you group both 2 adjacent elements and another(!) 3 adjacent elements in one merge operation.